# Second Monitor does not display after reconnecting VGA

Tags: 14.04, display, vga

I have a dell Latitude 3440 running Ubuntu 15.04. I have this connected up to a second monitor using VGA. As soon as I disconnect the cable and try and reconnect again the second display will not work. 
Only if I restart  the computer can I get monitor to display again. I have tried different laptops and don't encounter this problem, so I have ruled out faulty cable and monitor issues.

Comment: Have you ever tried to press super key ( windows key ) and hold than hit P? There're 3 options...One is a copy of the main screen, than there's turning off the main and push it to the other and lastly is having two screens work as one. This is the some for windows btw. Even when your not connected 2 an other screen, holding super key and pressing on P will make your screen flicker. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem on the same laptop so it might be model-related. The fastest workaround is to sleep-resume (which sadly does not always work with me), or restart X server by pressing Alt-SysRq-k. The second option will force close your session but all the running programs will stay in memory so will restart very fast afterwards.

Comment: yeah, sleep and recover sometimes works for me too.